# Failed to execute goal Spring Framework Maven

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a project_1 which is using JAR of project_2.
project_2 is using the spring framework.

project_2 builds successfully but project_1 fails with below error using 'mvn clean install' command:

**Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.4:repackage on project : xxx
: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.4:repackage failed:
Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring:boot-maven-plugin:2.5.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved.
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:jar2.5.4 Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-buildpack-platform:pom:2.5.4 from artifact repository: Failed to transfer file http://repo.xxx.com/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-builpack-platform-2.5.4 with status code 308**

I tried below command on project_1

" mvn clean install -U"

but it does not help.

One more thing I noticed:

Project_1 has following lines

```
<build> 
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and If I comment above plugin everything works perfectly.
But do not know if commenting it is a good idea or not.

Comment: Use **https** for the repository not **http**.

Comment: Tried both http and https, it does not work.

Comment: https should work however without knowing which repository you are using this will be impossible to answer. a 308 means it has been moved, this code is given for most dependencies coming from the old HTTP maven website or even the JCentre ones.

Comment: There are times where there is an intermittent failure with a repo.  Is this an internal repo or a standard one?

Comment: Internal repo @stdunbar